# Access private static method from outside the class C++

Tags: c++, methods, static, private, invoke

How exactly can you access a private static method from outside the class. Say, I have a class

```
    Class ABC {
    private:
        static void print(string str) {
            cout << "It works!!!" << endl;
        }
    };
```

Now, I just to call print() function say from another function like:

```
    void doSomething() {
         string str = "1776a0";
         // Call to print() here
    }
```

I have searched the internet and stackoverflow for such a problem but I couldn't find much.
So, please point me in the right direction as to if this is possible or not and if so how to do it.

I am currently using GCC.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: You cant its `private`. If it was `public` you could use `ABC::print(str)`

Comment: The whole point with `private` methods is for them to ONLY be accessed from within the class. I would either change it to `public`, or add a new method that calls `print()` and is public (not sure what that would accomplish though).

Comment: You don't - that's why it's private.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. That is exactly what `private` means.  If it is intended to be callable from outside the class, make it `public`.

Instead of making it `public` you could call it from another function that *is* publicly accessible. This other function could either be a public member of `ABC`, or a `friend` function.

Both cases require changing the class definition of `ABC`.

If the other function just does nothing besides call `print()` then you have achieved the same effect as making `print()` public. But presumably `print` is private for a reason, e.g. it relies on some preconditions. You could make the other function allow for that. For example:

```
void abc_printer(string printer_name, string str_to_print)
{
    open_printer(printer_name);          
    ABC::print(str);                         
    close_printer();
}
```

and inside the class definition of `ABC`:

```
friend void abc_printer(string, string);
```

Comment: I think a code sample of how to use `friend` for this might be in order

Answer (score 0):

You can if you know the address of function:

```
typedef void (*funcPtr)();

class beforeABC
{
public:
    static int getRange() 
    {
        char* funcAddr = (char*)&(beforeABC::func);
        char* endAddr = (char*)&(beforeABC::end);
        return endAddr - funcAddr;
    }
    static void func() { };
    static void end() { };
};

class ABC
{
private:
    static void print()
    {
        cout << "It works!!!" << endl;
    }
public:
    static void func() 
    { 
        // does not works without this line. Can someone explain this?
        if(0 == (unsigned long int)&print);
    };
};

int main()
{
    ABC::func();

    funcPtr f = (funcPtr)((char*)&(beforeABC::end) + beforeABC::getRange());
    f();

    return 0;
}
```

It is just a hack. Very unsafe and compiler\system dependent. Do not use it in real projects.

Comment: Unused functions might be removed by the linker.  I'm surprised that line changed whether the function was considered "unused", the expression can still be optimized to `true` without referencing the function.

Comment: Instead of going to all that trouble you could just change `private` to `public` in the ABC header. Still unsafe and compiler/system dependent but maybe not quite as much so as in this example

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, asking a friend I found another way:
By making the doSomething() function friend of the class ABC.

Answer (score 0):

A great hack (just for proof of concept, DO NOT CODE LIKE THIS!!!)
is for example
put a break point in the context you need
for example main.cpp:21

let us assume our function is static void for simplicty

so I will declare in main.cpp:22

```
void (*func_p) () = nullptr;
func_p();
```

I will advance until line 22 with the break point and will print the address of my static function

in GDB you can use `print giladStruct::myfunc` or `b giladStruct::myfunc`
this will return the address something like

```
{void (void)} 0x7fffcf5bf112 <giladStruct::myfunc()>
```

then you need to `set func_p = 0x7fffcf5bf112`
and continue to run.

The address will change but for a POC/simple hack this will work.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a newcomer to C++, but you can access private static methods via pointers passed as callbacks, which still allows one to assure the methods cannot be called directly. This can be done without requiring a friend function, since the callback pointer is registered using the constructor of the class. For example, the following would make the "print" method available as a call back, without allowing the direct invocation of the print method:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void RegisterCallback(void (* const fn)(void));

class ABC 
{
public:
    ABC() {RegisterCallback((void (*)(void))&ABC::print);}
private:
    static void print(void) 
    {
        cout << "It works!!!" << endl;
    }
};

int main(void)
{
    ABC abc;
    return 0;
}

void RegisterCallback(void (* const fn)(void))
{
    fn();
}
```